# splitting circle into two using LineString Python Shapely

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I have created a circle using Shapely and would like to split it into two using LineString.

I created the circle as follows

```
from functools import partial

import pyproj
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, shape, MultiPoint, LineString, mapping 
from shapely.ops import transform, split

radius = 92600
lon = 54.08
lat = 17.05

local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(
    lat, lon
)
wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
    pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
)
aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
    pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
)

center = Point(float(lon), float(lat))
point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, center)
buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius)
# Get the polygon with lat lon coordinates
circle_poly = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer)
```

For the line Splitter I have the following:

```
splitter = LingString([Point(54.79,16.90), Point(53.56,16.65)])
```

Now I want to see the two split shapes so I used split function.

```
result = split(circle_poly, splitter)
```

However, this only results the same circle and not two shapes.
At the end I would like to use one section of the split to form another shape.

Answer (score 2):

To split a circle or a polygon, you can use spatial `difference` operation with another polygon. Shapely does not allow the use of `line` to do so.

```
"Shapely can not represent the difference between an object and a lower dimensional object (such as the difference between a polygon and a line or point) as a single object."
```

[See document:](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-analysis-methods)

In your case, you can build two polygons that have the `line` as the common edges.
Make sure that the 2 polygons together are big enough to cover the whole polygon you are splitting. Then you use that polygons to do the job.

If you want crude results from the `difference` operation,
you can turn the line into a slim polygon by `buffer` operation, and use it.

For the second approach, here is the relevant code:

```
the_line = LineString([(54.95105, 17.048144), (53.40473921, 17.577181)])
buff_line = the_line.buffer(0.000001)  #is polygon

# the `difference` operation between 2 polygons
multi_pgon = circle_poly.difference(buff_line)
```

The result is a multi-polygon geometry object.

[image: diff-oper]

Comment: Thanks for your tip. However, I cannot use multi_pgon[0] or multi_pgon[1]. I get an error "'Polygon' object is not subscriptable".
I would appreciate your help

Comment: if the result is of type MultiPolygon, you can call .geoms[0] and .geoms[1] respectively.